# If a row from JOIN table, do not exist, Nothing echo (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Confusing title right? Let me explain: Here is the code:

```
SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT videos.videos_name) as videos_name
FROM tmdb_movies 
JOIN videos ON videos.videos_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
Where tmdb_movies.tmdb_id='31'
GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title
```

Now this code echo nothing. Because  `Where tmdb_movies.tmdb_id='31'` do not exist in `videos` table. But at least`tmdb.movies.movie_title` should echo.

How to make other things echo, if a row do not exist in one of the JOIN line?

If you did not understand the question, let me explain my table structure:

In this code, there are 2 tables named: `tmdb_movies` and `videos`. I am using one to many relationship. Both tables are connected to each other using `tmdb_id`

This is how my `tmdb_movies` table looks like:

```
tmdb_id       movie_title
1             Ironman
2             Logan
3             Boy
4             Superman
```

And this is how my `videos` table looks like:

```
videos_tmdb_id       videos_name
1                    Ironman Trailer
2                    Logan Trailer #1
2                    Logan Trailer #2
3                    Boy Trailer #1
3                    Boy teaser 
4                    Superman Trailer #1
4                    Superman Teaser
```

And i connected them via a foreign key like this: 
[image]

Please let me know, if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` like:

```
SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT videos.videos_name) as videos_name
FROM tmdb_movies 
LEFT JOIN videos ON videos.videos_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
Where tmdb_movies.tmdb_id='31'
GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title
```

and try again.

[Left Join Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Comment: Worked, that was easy

Comment: Which is the default JOIN? Self Join?

Comment: Its `inner join`, `self join` is the one is which you can join a sigle table by making two alias of it.

Comment: On a sidenote: As so often w3schools proves a weak reference; quote: "In some databases LEFT JOIN is called LEFT OUTER JOIN." No, it's `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, but the keyword `OUTER` is optional and can be ommited (just as `INNER` is optional in  `INNER JOIN`).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks for the update. You guys are like knowledge repository for us.